# Making a table from a string

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use JavaScript to take something like this:

```
<div class="content">Fruit<br>
Apple: 100 - 250<br>
Orange: 90 - 190<br>
Pear: 140 - 230<br>
Melon: 1000 - 1280</div>
```

And put it into a table like this:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><th>Fruit</th><th>Min</th><th>Max</th><th>Difference</th></tr><tr><td>Apple</td><td>100</td><td>250</td><td>150</td></tr><tr><td>Orange</td><td>90</td><td>190</td><td>100</td></tr><tr><td>Pear</td><td>140</td><td>230</td><td>90</td></tr><tr><td>Melon</td><td>1000</td><td>1280</td><td>280</td></tr></table>
```

I'm having trouble finding a place to start.

Comment: You could use javascript to parse these and add them to a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates a table based on the content from the div "content" when the user clicks the button.

```js
(function(){
  var content = document.getElementById("content");
  var tresult = document.getElementById("tresult");
  var btnCreateTable = document.getElementById("btnCreateTable");
  
  //adds event listener to button
  btnCreateTable.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    //parse and create table
    parseContent(content);
  });

  function parseContent(oCon){
    var nodes = content.innerText;
    var sNodes = nodes.split("\n");
    var newTable = "";
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    //sColumns is used to def the columns for the table
    var sColumns = [
      "Fruit",
      "Min",
      "Max",
      "Difference"
    ];

    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(a = 0; a < sColumns.length; a++){
      var th = document.createElement('th');
      th.innerText = sColumns[a];
      tr.appendChild(th);        
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);

    var oFruit = [],
        oMin = [],
        oMax = [],
        oNumbers = [];

    for(b = 1; b < sNodes.length; b++){
      var sFruit = sNodes[b].split(":");
      for(c = 0; c < sFruit.length; c++){
        if(c % 2 === 0){
          oFruit.push(sFruit[c]);
        }else{
          oNumbers.push(sFruit[c]);
        }
      }        
    }

    for(var d = 0; d < oNumbers.length; d++){
      var spNum = oNumbers[d].split("-");
      oMin.push(spNum[0]);
      oMax.push(spNum[1]);
    }

    for(var f = 0; f < sNodes.length - 1; f++){   
      var tr2 = document.createElement('tr');     
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerText = oFruit[f];
      tr2.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerText = oMin[f];
      tr2.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerText = oMax[f];
      tr2.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerText = oMax[f] - oMin[f];
      tr2.appendChild(td);
      table.appendChild(tr2);
    }

    tresult.appendChild(table);
  }; 
}());
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content" class="content">Fruit<br>
      Apple: 100 - 250<br>
      Orange: 90 - 190<br>
      Pear: 140 - 230<br>
      Melon: 1000 - 1280
    </div>
    <div id="tresult"></div>
    <button id="btnCreateTable">Create table</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This helps so much. Thanks a lot!

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: In addition, this answer would be significantly improved by putting the code into a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Using a snippet also makes it more likely for it to be up-voted, because people can quickly verify that your code functions correctly. While snippets shouldn't always be used, for JavaScript/HTML/CSS based questions and answers, they can significantly improve communicating both the problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is too hard coded but you can use as a base.

```js
var myControl =  $('.content');
var inputData = myControl.text().split('\n');
 $('.content').remove();

var table = "<table><tr><th>" + inputData[0] + "</th><th>Min</th><th>Max</th><th>Difference</th></tr>";

for (var i = 1; i < inputData.length; i++) 
{ 
    var cells = inputData[i].replace(': ', ' ').replace(' - ',' ').split(' ');
    
    table += "<tr><th>"+cells[0]+"</th><th>"+cells[1]+"</th><th>"+ +cells[2] +"</th><th>"+ (parseInt(cells[2]) - parseInt(cells[1]))  +"</th></tr>"    
};

table+="</table>"

$("body").append(table);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">Fruit<br>
Apple: 100 - 250<br>
Orange: 90 - 190<br>
Pear: 140 - 230<br>
Melon: 1000 - 1280</div>
```